# showing null while passing & fetching data from other class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, uiviewcontroller

There are two classes `DropDownPicker` and  `editAddVehicle` Class. Simply I have declare a string variable in `editAddVehicle` with name "`brandID1`" and I want it to bring data from `DropDownPicker` Class.

Here is my code:

**DropDownPicker.h**

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *selectedIndex;
```

**DropDownPicker.m**

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

   if ([[dataArrayForPicker objectAtIndex:row] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
      NSLog(@"Selected %@. Index is: %i brand id %@" , [dataArrayForPicker objectAtIndex:row], row,_selectedIndex[row]);
      editAddVehicle *controller=[[editAddVehicle alloc]init];
      controller.brandID1=_selectedIndex[row];
      NSLog(@"Brand Id %@",controller.brandID1);
      // Brand Id 50
      self->pickerTextFeild.text = [dataArrayForPicker objectAtIndex:row];
   }
   else 
      self->pickerTextFeild.text = [dataArrayForPicker objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

From `DropDownPicker` through this line `controller.brandID1=_selectedIndex[row];` of code easily I have stored string in `crandID1` but why its still showing null at `editAddVehicle.m` ?

**EditAddVehicle.h**

```
@interface editAddVehicle : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *brandID1;
@end
```

**EditAddVehicle.m**

```
@interface editAddVehicle()<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    NSString *brandID1;  
}
@end

@implementation editAddVehicle
@synthesize brandID1;
{
    UITextField *textFeild1=(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:10];
    brand= [[DropDownPicker alloc]initWithTextFeild:textFeild1 withData:brandArray];
    [brand setPlaceHolder:@"Brand"];
    brand.selectedIndex=brandCode;
    [brand addTarget:self action:@selector(brandSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

-(void)brandSelected:(DropDownPicker *)sender{
    NSLog(@"%@",brandID1);
    // (null) why ?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wrong way to pass data you need to user delegate or NSNotificationCenter for pass data .

Here MY EXample for NSNotificationCenter

// IN DropDownPicker

```
   - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
    if ([[dataArrayForPicker objectAtIndex:row] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
       NSLog(@"Selected %@. Index is: %i brand id %@" , [dataArrayForPicker objectAtIndex:row], row,_selectedIndex[row]);
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"NotificationForData" object:_selectedIndex[row]];

    }
        else{ 
self->pickerTextFeild.text = [dataArrayForPicker objectAtIndex:row];
// un comment if you want pass data here
// [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"NotificationForData" object:_selectedIndex[row]];
        }

}
```

IN editAddVehicle
    // in viewdidload

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(brandSelected:) name:@"NotificationForData" object:nil];

-(void)brandSelected:(NSNotification*)noti{
    NSString *brandID1 = [noti object];
    NSLog(@"%@",brandID1);
}
```

Comment: Well tried your suggested way too sir but dint work again the same thing null is reflecting.

Comment: did you check  [noti object]; ?

Comment: ooh Sorry! it worked Thanks a lot for this Valuable suggestion or answer.

Comment: Just to add up, always remove the observer in the deinit method of your viewController whenever you use notifications. Also I'd always prefer using delegations over notifications wherever possible.